# Object en formulario Spring

Tags: spring, java-ee, object

Tengo un formulario en el que tengo unos input en los que al rellenar mediante js los recojo y los añado a un input hidden que tengo por la pagina.

```
document.editRouteForm.itinerary.value = itiToObj();
document.editRouteForm.itinerary.value = JSON.stringify(itiToObj());
```

El primero me añade esta información en el campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el segundo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez llega al controlador me da un fallo el BindingResult que me dice lo siguiente (este es si hago JSON.stringfy):

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'route' on field 'itinerary': rejected value [{"name":"ch","color":"chjjhfd","salidasEntradas":["1","2","3"]}]; codes [typeMismatch.route.itinerary,typeMismatch.itinerary,typeMismatch.es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.Itinerary,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [route.itinerary,itinerary]; arguments []; default message [itinerary]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.Itinerary' for property 'itinerary'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.Itinerary' for property 'itinerary': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

(este si devuelvo el objeto):

```
Field error in object 'route' on field 'itinerary': rejected value [[object Object]]; codes [typeMismatch.route.itinerary,typeMismatch.itinerary,typeMismatch.es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.Itinerary,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [route.itinerary,itinerary]; arguments []; default message [itinerary]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.Itinerary' for property 'itinerary'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.Itinerary' for property 'itinerary': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Entonces con este error me aseguro que la informacion llega al backend pero no es capaz de procesarlo.

Este es el objeto con el que estoy trabajando:

```
public class Itinerary implements Serializable {

 private String name;
 private String[] salidasEntradas;
 private String color;

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String[] getSalidasEntradas() {
  return salidasEntradas;
 }

 public void setSalidasEntradas(String[] salidasEntradas) {
  this.salidasEntradas = salidasEntradas;
 }

 public String getColor() {
  return color;
 }

 public void setColor(String color) {
  this.color = color;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Itinerary{" + "name=" + name + ", salidasEntradas=" + salidasEntradas + ", color=" + color + '}';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los dos escenarios que tienes son los siguientes:

1. Intentas meter un objeto JS como valor de un formulario. No funciona porque todos los valores deben ser un string. Y cualquier objeto se transforma a string de ese modo, poniendo `[object Object]`.
2. Haces un JSON.stringify del objeto: Obtienes un string.

En ambos casos pasa lo mismo: Spring recibe un campo con un `String`, pero tienes definido que debería ser un objeto `Itinerary`.

Veo dos soluciones:

1. Añade a tu form:

   - Un input hidden con `name="itinerary.name"`
   - Un input hidden con `name="itinerary.color"`
   - Un input hidden con `name="itinerary.salidasEntradas"` **por cada valor de salidasEntradas que tengas**.
2. Modifica tu objeto Route para que el setter de Itinerary admita un String y lo procese como JSON, generando el Itinerary

Comment: Gracias me sirvió de ayuda tu aclaración